# How to automatically send emails in html

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

I am making a form and I want it to email me whenever somebody completes it. Does anybody know if this can be done in HTML alone or if this has to utilize something more? So basically I want to know if it is possible for when a button is pressed, if that can send an email. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="mailto:yourmailadress@xxx.com?Subject=Mail Subject" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

This is the process of sending mail that can be done with html without using a different language.

Comment: I guess this one really only works if you have the right default emailing app selected. whenever I click send, it always prompts me (at least with default mail, and microsaft outlook set as default emailing apps) to send the email and then I can send it. is there anything at doesnt prompt me and just goes to send it automatically? also, thank you for responding :)

Comment: If you want it to be sent automatically, you need to combine these html codes with a different programming language.

Comment: would you happen to know anything about that? I would love  to know.